# Javascript prints <br>

Tags: javascript

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var dataText = ["Text on line one <br /> Text on line 2"];
function typeWriter(text, i, fnCallback) {
if (i < (text.length)) {
document.querySelector(".animate").innerHTML = text.substring(0, i+1) +'<span aria-hidden="true"></span>';
setTimeout(function() {
typeWriter(text, i + 1, fnCallback)
}, 75);
}
else if (typeof fnCallback == 'function') {
}
}
function StartTextAnimation(i) {
if (typeof dataText[i] == 'undefined'){
setTimeout(function() {
StartTextAnimation(0);
}, 20000);
}
    if (i < dataText[i].length) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        typeWriter(dataText[i], 0, function(){
          StartTextAnimation(i + 1);
        });
      }, 1000);
    }
}
StartTextAnimation(0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="animate"></p>
```

as you can see, the "<" gets printed for a very short time, is there any way to prevent this? adding the break in the HTML code and removing it from the JS code does not work

Comment: I don't see it printed

Comment: Just closing because despite of StackOverflow informing you to post the code here, you didn't.

Comment: It is printed for a very short time

Comment: You could use a `\n` character instead, and then replace it with `<br />` before assigning to `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope the below works. Updated code in `typeWriter` function. The code checks for index/position of `<br />` and increments the counter, updates `innerHTML` and then calls the `typeWriter` function again.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 var dataText = ["Text on line one <br /> Text on line 2 <br /> Text on line 3"];

 function typeWriter(text, i, fnCallback) {
  if (i < (text.length)) {

   //Updated code starts here
   if (i == text.indexOf("<br />", i)) {
    i += "<br />".length;
    document.querySelector(".animate").innerHTML += "<br />";
   }
   else
    document.querySelector(".animate").innerHTML = text.substring(0, i + 1) + '<span aria-hidden="true"></span>';
   //Updated code ends here

   setTimeout(function () { typeWriter(text, i + 1, fnCallback) }, 75);
  }
  else if (typeof fnCallback == 'function') { }
 }

 function StartTextAnimation(i) {
  if (typeof dataText[i] == 'undefined') {
   setTimeout(function () {
    StartTextAnimation(0);
   }, 20000);
  }
  if (i < dataText[i].length) {
   setTimeout(function () {
    typeWriter(dataText[i], 0, function () {
     StartTextAnimation(i + 1);
    });
   }, 1000);
  }
 }
 
 StartTextAnimation(0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="animate"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that you get the characters one by one,

```
text.substring(0, i+1)
```

so the `<` gets added first then `b` then `r` and finally `>`

When you can do, is set a condition that when you find a special character like `<` you will read all the characters at once until the enclosing `>`

So, for example this would work:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var dataText = ["Text on line one <br> Text on line 2"];
function typeWriter(text, i, fnCallback) {
if (i < (text.length)) {
if (text.charAt(i) === '<') {
  // Get the index of the enclosing > tag
  var tempIndex = text.indexOf('>', i);
  // Add all the code from the < until the enclosing >
  var textToAdd = text.substr(i, tempIndex + 1);
  i = tempIndex;
} else {
  // If the character isn't a < just do the operation normally
  textToAdd = text.substring(0, i +1);
}
document.querySelector(".animate").innerHTML = 
textToAdd +'<span aria-hidden="true"></span>';
setTimeout(function() {
typeWriter(text, i + 1, fnCallback)
}, 75);
}
else if (typeof fnCallback == 'function') {
}
}
function StartTextAnimation(i) {
if (typeof dataText[i] == 'undefined'){
setTimeout(function() {
StartTextAnimation(0);
}, 20000);
}
    if (i < dataText[i].length) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        typeWriter(dataText[i], 0, function(){
          StartTextAnimation(i + 1);
        });
      }, 1000);
    }
}
StartTextAnimation(0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="animate"></p>
```

Comment: Now you have a bounce effect.

Comment: @ScottMarcus That's another issue which could be solved using CSS. The issue where the `<` was printed before the line break is solved.

Comment: Uh, no it's not. The bounce effect was not in the OP's result. Your code changes caused it.